# Using "years" as a unit denomination is deprecated

Tags: solidity

I'm getting this warning:

```
 Warning: Using "years" as a unit denomination is deprecated.
    uint date = now + 1 years;
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use days instead, so now + 365 days. it has been deprecated because not every year is composed by 365 days.